# Connecting with Bluetooth L2Cap to HID Device

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, jsr82, l2cap

Are there any workarounds to connect to HID device using L2CAP in JAVA ME (using JSR-82 specification implementation native to mobile device not BlueCove etc.)?

I know that HID devices usually uses PSMs (Protocol Service Multiplexor) with 0x0011 value. Unfortunately as I found:

> Legal PSM values are in the range (0x1001..0xFFFF), and the least significant byte must be odd and all other bytes must be even.

Above explains why `javax.microedition.io.Connector connect()` method throws exception when I try following code:

```
Connector.open("btl2cap://600010120296:11");
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr082/MR4changes.html) suggests that the restriction was removed in JSR-82 1.2:

> Legal PSM values are in the range (0x0005..0xFFFF), and the least significant byte must be odd and all other bytes must be even. When a server connection string does not have a psm parameter, the server PSM value assigned by the implementation must be no less than 0x1001.

And the comment:

> Remove reserved ranges from L2CAP PSM values, to allow a Java application to use a Bluetooth protocol that is built on top of L2CAP using a PSM value in the "reserved" range.

Also, the "interrupt endpoint" is PSM 0x13 (that's where keyboards, mice, etc will send unsolicited reports just like they would send on the control channel (0x11) in response to GET_REPORT).